# Fancybox: Nav buttons not showing, content in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, button, fancybox

I have a little problem with an images gallery on Fancybox 2.0.6.
I have no nav buttons showing, only the close one. So, I guess that I've made a mistake when I added the plugin in my gallery script so that it finds only one image. The problem isn't depending of the browser used, I get it on IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.
My gallery script is in PHP, like all the rest of my site. My images are stored in an array, created by a function which reads the folder content.

Here are my scripts.

Function get_files:

```
// Fonction de lecture du dossier et publication dans un tableau
function get_files($images_dir,$exts = array('jpg')) {
  $files = array();
  if($handle = opendir($images_dir)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      $extension = strtolower(get_file_extension($file));
      if($extension && in_array($extension,$exts)) {
        $files[] = $file;
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
  }
  return $files;
}
```

portfolio.php (gallery part)

```
$image_files = get_files($images_dir);
    if(count($image_files)) {
        $index = 0;
        $firstimage = $image_files[0];
        $thumb = $images_dir.'/'.$firstimage; //Lien: files/photos/$images_dir/premièreimage.JPG
        $page .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
        $page .= '$(".img_gallery").click(function() {';
        $page .= '$.fancybox.open([';
        foreach($image_files as $index=>$file) {
            $index++;
            // echo $file.'<br />';
            //Création des liens image pour javascript
            $link = $images_dir.'/'.$file;
            $page .= "{ href : '".$link."', title : '".$altname."' } ],";
        }
        // Création des liens de la galerie et fermeture du dossier
        $page .= '});</script>';
        $page .= '<h3>Open Gallery</h3><br /><br />';
        $page .= '<a class="img_gallery" href="'.$thumb.'" rel="gallery"><img src="'.$thumb.'" height="342" width="512" alt="Open Gallery" title="Open Gallery"/></a> ';
    }
    else {
      $page .= '<p>There are no images in this gallery.</p>';
    }
```

And here are the lines where I added the plugins:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<!-- Gallery Initiators -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*$("a[rel='gallery']").fancybox();*/
        $("a[rel='gallery']").fancybox(portfolio,{
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            nextEffet: 'fade',
            prevEffect: 'fade'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Could anyone explain me what's wrong and how to correct this ? I've got good skills in PHP, but I'm quite newbie to Javascript. 
Some details more: I cannot create each link for each image, I've got many galleries (set by a $_GET value) and some contain hundred and more images. Finally, I would like to have only the first image of each gallery showing on the page as the gallery link (manual call).

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: I've another question.. In order to get a valid HTML code (for W3 validator), I would like to use data-fancybox-gallery. From what I understand, it allows to get rid of "rel" attribute. Right ?

If so, how to implement it on my script ?

Answer (score 0):

For Nav Buttons and Link for each image:
You need have id on image elements for fancybox to automatically detect a array of images and then proceed from the first image which will eventually show you the nav buttons on both sides .

To just show the first image of every gallery, hide the whole container using css and in your java-script use window onload function to show just the first child of the parent element(which will be the container of your images). Hope it does make sense.

Comment: It's ok for the second part, it does make me sense.
I've some understanding problems with the first part, though.

Following my scripts above, I've got to set an id on image elements here, right ?
  $page .= "{ href : '".$link."', title : '".$altname."' } ],";

Comment: I am sorry it took me ages to reply again. yeah the id should be on image elements, add the same id for all the images, it should work fine. I am sorry again for the delay